# How do I add an extra field using ASP.Net membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have a basic app using the ASP.NET membership provider. By default, you can use a few fields such as username, password, remember me.

How do I add to the **asp.net membership provider** so I can add an additional field "address" in the register section and have it save to the database?

I currently see the following when creating a user in the account model:

```cs
public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password,
   string email)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
   { throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName"); }
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
   { throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "password"); }
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
   { throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email"); }

   MembershipCreateStatus status;
   _provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true,
       null, out status);

   return status;
}
```

In the create user function, I also want to save the user's "address".

In the **register.aspx** I added a the following:

```html
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Address) %>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As jwsample noted, you can use the Profile Provider for this.

Alternatively, you could create your own table(s) that store additional user-related information. This is a little more work since you're on the hook for creating your own tables and creating the code to get and save data to and from these tables, but I find that using custom tables in this way allows for greater flexibility and more maintainability than the Profile Provider (specifically, the default Profile Provider, SqlProfileProvider, which stores profile data in an inefficient, denormalized manner).

Take a look at this tutorial, where I walk through this process: [Storing Additional User Information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs).

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to use the Profile Provider for this, thats what it was meant for. If you modify the membership provider to add the additional field it will break the provider contract and you won't be able to switch to another in the future.

Here is the profile provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx

If you are using the sql membership provider than you probably have all the table structures installed to support the profile provider as well.

Answer (score 2):

**To add new column named "Address":**

**Step 1:** Models/IdentityModels.cs

Add the following code to the "ApplicationUser" class:

```
public string Address{ get; set; }
```

**Step 2:**  Models/AccountViewModels.cs

Add the following code to the "RegisterViewModel" class:

```
public string Address{ get; set; }
```

**Step 3:**  Views/Register.cshtml

Add Address input textbox to the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
</div>
```

**Step 4 :**

Go to Tools > NuGet Manager > Package Manager Console 
    Step A : Type “Enable-Migrations” and press enter 
    Step B : Type “ Add-Migration "Address" ” and press enter 
    Step C : Type “Update-Database” and press enter

i.e

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
PM> Add-Migration "Address"
PM> Update-Database
```

**Step 5:**  Controllers/AccountController.cs

Go to Register Action and add "Address= model.Address" to the ApplicationUser 
i.e

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Address= model.Address}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, Saved lots of hassle. Thank you, Could you please explain step 4. For me `.Net` has created some classes in a folder called `Migrations`, What are these? what will happen if I publish the project?

Comment: You can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-entity-framework-scaffolding-and-migrations for details