# altering the asp.net mvc default user account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-accounts

I've been trying to use the default accounting feature of MVC and it keeps failing.

I would like to change a couple of things in it but it doesn't seem to work.

1. I want to make the username to be the email.
2. I don't want to have the question and answer of the password fields. (When I tried to remove them it gave me an error that I didn't supply these items).
3. I want to add additional fields to the member like first name, last name, address and so on.

How can I achieve that? Is there a more dynamic way to do that instead of the default accounting feature of MVC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a custom membership provider. You might try the following article by Dan Harman. It should point you in the right direction.

[ASP.Net MVC 3 Custom Membership Provider with Repository Injection](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/)

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted. I wanted to be able to configure the membership provider with less or additional parameters such as first name, last name and to remove the password question and password answer.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there isn't a way to remove/change parameters (password question, etc) for the Membership provider. If you want to remove something you will have to implement your own provider. If you just want to track additional information you can do so using a profile provider. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435812/how-do-i-add-an-extra-field-using-asp-net-membership-provider