# How to Add Extra Fields of FistName and LastName in Userprofile of Asp.Net MVC 4 Simple Membership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I want to add 2 Extra fields in UserProfile Asp.Net Simple membership, But unable to add and not find any help from internet. Please give me some solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add an extra field using ASP.Net membership provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435812/how-do-i-add-an-extra-field-using-asp-net-membership-provider)

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. There are dozen of posts about adding fields to the User Profile table. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+mvc4+simplemembership+add+field&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=eh1lUt6fFfO00QXNwoGICg

Comment: Dear I am taking about Simple Membership which is newly add in MVC 4 not Asp.Net Membership Provider Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add fields to `UserProfile` in SimpleMembership (I will assume you want to use migrations and EF):

1. Ensure you have enabled migrations (use the `Enable-Migration` in the package manager console)
2. Edit the `UserProfile` class (assuming you are using, for example, the Visual Studio 2012 -> New Project -> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application -> Internet Application template, this will be created for you) to add your new properties (example below)
3. Add a migration which will update your database using the `Add-Migration` command.
4. Optionally edit the generated migration to handle default values and non-nullable fields.
5. Run that migration against your development database using the `Update-Database` command.

I have provided an overview about how SimpleMembership works, with UserProfile [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631). Note that UserProfile can be moved from the `UsersContext` to the same DbContext as all your other classes, it does not have to be in a separate context.

SimpleMembership is designed to play well with code-first EF development, so that is the process I have outlined above. An example updated `UserProfile` class with a `Forename`, `Surname` and a `LoginCount` field would look like:

```cs
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    [Required]
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(40)]
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LoginCount { get; set; }
}
```

References:

1. [ASP.NET MVC 4 Entity Framework Scaffolding and Migrations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-entity-framework-scaffolding-and-migrations) - task 3 shows how to enable migrations
2. [MSDN: Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) - everything you need to know about migrations
3. [StackOverflow: How do I use my own database with SimpleMembership and WebSecurity? What is MVC4 security all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631)